# rosserial helloworld

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to get the example helloWorld working from the rosserial package, and everything went smooth until the command: rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

the error msg is: raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'

I verified on the Arduino IDE that serial port is indeed /dev/ttyACM0
and #include "WProgram.h" has been changed to #include "Arduino.h".

My system is running ubuntu 12.04 fuerte build, and using Arduino 1.0 IDE.

Please let me know if anyone has encountered similiar problems, and how you solved this issue.
Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52093/rosserial-helloworld/) by [c22shen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3953/c22shen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer, this issue has been resolved by adding my own username to the dailout group.

sudo adduser  dialout
and after restarting my computer, there was no longer any permission issue involved.

Thanks again!

---

Originally posted by [c22shen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3953/c22shen/) with karma: 36 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the permissions of your USB device.
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0

if they're not sufficient, you can add them by typing 'sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0'.

However this will need redoing every time you unplug and replug it in. (This is due to how Ubuntu handles device permissions). To make it permanent you need do change/add the 'udev' rules for the arduino device. Here's a similar question about udevs, which might help:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9097/how-can-i-get-a-unique-device-path-for-my-arduinoftdi-device/

---

Originally posted by [Gav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3961/gav/) with karma: 478 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2